# Stop pandas from grouping the data when reading csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem, when I read a csv file with pandas and assign it the header to be row 0 with the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv(fileName, header = [0])
```

The first x columns on each row is being grouped and surrounded by parenthesis.
For example, if I have the following:

```
Version, temp, altitude, oxygen, pressure, gas_temp, NH3, NO2
1,189,2980,489.9,594,345,345,22,00
2,11,33,423,554.9,2345,32,22,01
```

When I try to print each row from the data frame, I get this:

```
(1,189,2980,489.9,594) 345 345 22 00
(2,11,33,423,554.9) 2345 32 22 01
```

And if I call `df['temp']` I get back `[345, 2345]` which is not correct because pandas is grouping the first x columns together.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Please check if the sample is correct. In fact, it is not: because of the spaces, there is no column `'temp'` but there is column `' temp'` (with a space).

Comment: could you please, share the screenshot of the csv file, this will help to solve the problem.

Comment: try to check if this is related to the fact that you have 8 column headers and 9 entries in each row (at least in the example above).

Answer (score 0):

The firsr important discrepancy in your data sample is that it:

- contains only **8** column names,
- but there are **9** data columns.

Another disorder is that column names should be separated **only** with
commas, but your input contains also spaces.

The cumulated effect of the above is that *read_csv* is "fooled" and can read
data in such a weird way. Actually, at the first attempt I replicated your
case, but the next time (and all following times) I got an **apparently**
proper result.

The reason I wrote "apparently" is that when you print `df.columns`,
you wil see another flaw:

```
Index(['Version', ' temp', ' altitude', ' oxygen', ' pressure', ' gas_temp',
       ' NH3', ' NO2'],
      dtype='object')
```

i.e. column names contain **initial spaces**, so an attempt to refer e.g.
to *temp* column throws exception:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'temp'
```

One thing you can do to read this file correctly is to pass *skipinitialspace=True*
parameter:

```
df = pd.read_csv(fileName, skipinitialspace=True, header=[0])
```

The result of reading is:

```
   Version  temp  altitude  oxygen  pressure  gas_temp  NH3  NO2
1      189  2980     489.9   594.0       345       345   22    0
2       11    33     423.0   554.9      2345        32   22    1
```

When you print `df.columns`, you will see that column names are without
initial spaces, so now these extra spaces in the header row are stripped.

Another detail in the way how *read_csv* operates is that it matches column names
with data columns **from the end**, so the "additional" column (in data rows)
is taken as the **index** column, with no name.

You can also add *index_col=[0]* parameter:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, skipinitialspace=True, index_col=[0], header=[0])
```

to specify explicitely that the initial column is the index.